# Android Studio Layout Auto Alignment

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, and no matter what I do whenever I add something such as a textview or button to it, I cannot make it the size I want it to. It always auto aligns itself to the sides or top. When I want to make a square it doesn't allow me to do it. It never allows me to put my button or textview where I want it to. How do I make it so I can place my stuff anywhere I want and whatever size I choose it to be?

Comment: Consider using [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html?hl=ES).

Comment: I am using relative layout, but a more detailed explanation would be when I drag in a Plain TextView, green broken lines start to appear aligning it automatically. If I try to move it a little bit to the left it snaps it back to the middle

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using linear layout,You can use relative layout instead for start, although if you want to put a lot of buttons its getting harder to work with relative layout and linear layout is more organized go to you'r `xml` and there edit the in the first line where it says `<LinearLayout...` to `<RelativeLayout>` and don't forget to do the same at closing,I recommend you to watch a video on youtube on how to work with linear layouts.

Answer (score 0):

In RelativeLayout, it enable the attributes like `alignParentRight="true/false"` for exact right position and so on...
`layout_below="@id/tool/viewID_below_you_want_to_put"` and same for other side
so you can use it

For Example,

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/txt1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt1"
android:alignParentRight="true"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

which will make your textview in left and then button in right of textview

If you want to set it in center tou can set `gravity="center | center_vertical | center_horizontal"`

also you can set size as you want in width or height like 
`android:layout_width="50dp"`